# How can I delete data from my array with the key value?

Tags: php, session, post

I am trying to delete all the data from within a specific key in my array, but cant work out why my code isn't working. I have used `print_r` to check the code works and I can see that the correct value is being printed for each array when I click the 'remove' button, but it isn't removing the data from the key.

My current array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => S30813-Q100-X303
            [1] => 5
            [2] => Refurbished
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => JX-1T1-LTU
            [1] => 8
            [2] => New
        )

)
```

I am outputting the data to a table with:

```
        for ($row = 0; $row < $totalcount; $row++) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
            echo "<td>".$contents[$row][$col]."</td>";

            }
        for ($col = 0; $col < 1; $col++) {

            $del = $row;
            echo "<td><form action='' method='post'><input type='text' name='del' value=".$row."></input><input type='submit' name='deletepart' value='Remove'></input></form></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        }
```

Front-end:
[image]

My php to unset the array key (and where I am guessing the problem lies) is:

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['deletepart'])) {
        $value_to_delete = $_POST['del'];
        $value_to_delete = $key;

        unset($_SESSION['arr'][$key]);
        $_SESSION["arr"] = array_values($_SESSION["arr"]);
    }

?>
```

Any help on where I am going wrong here would be very much appreciated!

Comment: where is `$key` data comes?

Comment: You are overwriting the value for `$value_to_delete` in `$value_to_delete=$key` replace it with `$key = $value_to_delete`

Comment: @AbdullahRazzaki ...That has done it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

write `$key = $value_to_delete;` instead of `$value_to_delete = $key`

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['deletepart'])) {
        $value_to_delete = $_POST['del'];
        //$value_to_delete = $key; //instead of this use
         $key = $value_to_delete;

        unset($_SESSION['arr'][$key]);
        $_SESSION["arr"] = array_values($_SESSION["arr"]);
    }

?>
```

Comment: or use `unset($_SESSION['arr'][$_POST['del']]);`